# Como Reutilizar um component com outro css - Styled Components

Tags: css, react, typescript, styled-components, react-dom

Seguinte, juro que testei vários métodos mas não obtive sucesso. Tenho esse componente de Button que está na cor verde, e gostaria que sempre que eu reutilizar ele eu possa trocar o Background para outra cor. help

(estou utilizando typescript)

```
interface Props{
  title: string;
  icon?: string;
  path?: string;
}


const Button  = ({title, icon, path}: Props) => {
  return ( 
    <Container>
      <a href={path}>
        <img src={icon}/>
        {title}
      </a>
    </Container>

  
  ) 
}

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que esteja utilizando styled-components, então você passará o props para o style:

```
<Container redColor={true}>
```

No arquivo style

```
background-color: ${props => (redColor ? `red` : `green`)};
```

Não esqueça de inserir a tipagem:

```
interface MyColorsProp{redColor : boolean}
```

E declarar no component dentro do style

```
export const Container = styled.div<MyColorsProp>...
```

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso mas sem usar boolean  

defini a Interface: Newbackground? : string; 

passei pro componente a propriedade: Newbackground={Newbackground}  

defini no styled:  background: ${props => (props.Newbackground)};

 e chamei a propriedade em outra pagina:     <Button  Newbackground='#67A10F'  />